# trying to write media to another server

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup, http-request

i am trying to write media to another server is it possible:

i have 2 servers i need to put my magento code on 1st server and want all media on another server when we upload images of catalog,

how it can be possible i have changed Option.php but it throws exception "Unable to create directory 'http://test.xyz.com/web_media/tmp/catalog/product'"

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Create a Sub-domain named "media.mytestsite.com".

Copy the media folder to your sub-domain's root folder.

Give the permission 777 to media folder. (Full permission).
Go to you magento admin. Go to System -> Configuration -> Web -> Unsecure -> Base Media URL and put "http://media.mytestsite.com/media/".
```

5.Go to System -> Configuration -> Web -> Secure -> Base Media URL and put "https://media.mytestsite.com/media/".

```
Now save the configuration.

Clear/Refresh magento cache.(It is very important)
```

I hope it will work

**If you are using amazon..**

Refer to the links below

http://techsupport.nitish.info/2013/06/move-magento-stores-media-directory-to.html

http://thinkglobal.co/resources/moving-the-magento-media-directory-to-s3/

Comment: thanks for your comment but by this approch i am able to get images but not able to upload images